# php dynamic URL rewrite with a form submit to clean URL

Tags: php, forms, url, redirect

I know a lot can go wrong during a URL rewrite, which is why google recommends against converting URL's to clean URLs' if you don't fully understand what you're doing.

I want to ask if this is the correct way to go about this?

I have a site that is structured like so:

www.example.com/index.php?widget=blue&size=10&weight=50

I am using the mod_rewrite to make it so a clean URL could be used like:

www.example.com/blue/10-inches/50-grams/

I've accomplished this with the following code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^([a-zA-Z-]+)/([0-9-]+)-inches/([0-9-]+)-grams/?$    index.php? widget=$1&size=$2&weight=$3    [NC,L]
```

that makes this portion work..  however there's a form on the index page as well that changes the products on the index.php page based on the drop down box selections and the submit button being pressed.

```
Dropdown 1 = blue, red, green
Dropdown 2 = 10, 20, 30
Dropdown 3 = 25, 50, 100
```

What happens here by default is when you select say, red, 20, 100 and click submit, you'll get the old URL like  www.example.com/index.php?widget=red&size=20&weight=100

How could I do the redirection here? I'm currently working on doing it this way:

Change the `<form action="index.php" method="GET">`  to `<form action="redirect-url.php" method="GET">`

That new redirect-url.php will have the following code:

```
<?php
    header('Location: www.example.com/'.$_GET[widget].'/'.$_GET[size].'/'.$_GET[weight].'/');
    exit();

?>
```

Which should cause the apache RewriteRule I posted above to make it work.

Thoughts? Will this work? Is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you wouldn't use a url_rewrite when submitting a form as there isn't a default way to build the url. There are two ways around it. First is like you said, use an intermediate page to take the form values and do a header redirect to the url rewrite page. Second would be to use javascript to build the rewrite url and go there. I would suggest doing both. By default, have the form submit to a page that will do a redirect. Then on the form, use javascript and add an onsubmit event that will get the values and change the action of the form to the redirect page. That way there isn't an unnecessary redirect if javascript is enabled and if javascript is disabled you still have the redirect page as a fallback.